# Browser user agent resource

Tags: iis-6, user-agent, logging

I have a client who says he is using ie7 from two different sites however our iis logs are showing two different user agents one beginning

```
Mozilla/5.0+
```

the other

```
Mozilla/4.0+
```

This change occurred on Tuesday.

Does anyone know of a good resource for browsers and the various user agents they pump out?

Does anyone know the difference between the two user agents above?

Thanks in advance,
Patrick

Answer (score 1):

Try:

http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/browser_ids.htm

Answer (score 1):

Last updated in 2009, you may find this useful:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/browsercaps.aspx